# How to get an audio filed packed in the apk archive to play in the app for android?

Tags: android, audio, assets

OK so I have a Woohoo.mp3 in my "assets" folder of my project
also after packing the .apk I do find it residing in the assets folder

audioPlayer("file:///android_assets/Woohoo.mp3");

or

audioPlayer("file://android_assets/Woohoo.mp3");

did not work...
here is my audioPlayer method:

public void audioPlayer(String fileName){
        //set up MediaPlayer

```
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(fileName);
    try {
        AssetManager manager = getBaseContext().getAssets();
        AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = manager.openFd(fileName);
        long start = descriptor.getStartOffset();
        long end = descriptor.getLength();
        mp.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), start, end);
        //File file = new File(fileName);
        //FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        //mp.setDataSource(getBaseContext(),uri);
        //mp.setDataSource(fis.getFD());
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();

    } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                e.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mp.release();
        }

    });
    mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
};
```

}

I've been looking at this site and some other forums for few hours and tried a few methods and NONE of them worked for me....I wonder where I did wrong here... thanks

Answer (score 0):

For using Assets u have to give only the FileName not the FilePath.

Try using only Woohoo.mp3